# Change URL based on display width

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, width, detect

I created a [hobby site](http://www.gooplusplus.com) a few years ago that started as a convenient compact one-line-entry multi-search site. Later, I added various web tools, one-click radio stations, and other enhancements.

At first, I optimized for 1024x768 screens but tried to accommodate 800x600 screens. However, wide screen format is becoming dominant, so I decided it would be better to optimize things a bit by splitting the code, mostly, but not limited to, CSS changes, based on detecting a minimum 960 pixel width.

Screen widths less than 960 pixels wide redirect to a "mini.php" version.

The javascript code below selects the appropriate URL correctly if the web browser is already open. However, when initially opening a browser, the "mini" version is incorrectly selected regardless of the screen width. I tried delaying detection by using setTimeout() without effect.

```
var myWidth = 981

function vpWidth() {
return( myWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth );
}
vpWidth(); setTimeout(vpWidth,300);

if(myWidth<960) document.location.href="http://www.gooplusplus.com/mini.php";
```

Who can provide a solution that always works and not just when the browser is already open?

Comment: where do you set myWidth?

Comment: After more testing, it seems that the incorrect / unwanted redirection to "mini.php" upon browser start is limited to Google Chrome and Chromium-based browsers such Opera Next, SRware Iron, and Torch. It oNLY occurs when opening a browser where the "last tab focus" was not our subject site, gooplusplus.com, but some other site such as stackoverflow.com. (Revised browser test results.)

Answer (score 2):

You're never actually setting `myWidth`. Also, I replaced your function with how jQuery gets the width internally.

```
function vpWidth() {
    return Math.max(document.documentElement["clientWidth"], document.body["scrollWidth"], document.documentElement["scrollWidth"], document.body["offsetWidth"], document.documentElement["offsetWidth"]);
}
var myWidth = vpWidth();

if(myWidth<960) document.location.href="http://www.gooplusplus.com/mini.php";
```

Comment: actually, I did but tried simplifying the code for this posting. (My bad.) I will update and change it back.

Comment: That's okay, I just edited my answer with the calculation that jQuery uses internally to check the width of the viewport.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to work. I added some alert() statements for testing.

Alert A [ after new vpWidth() function ] passed.
Alert B [ after myWidth = vpWidth(); statement ] failed.

BTW, this PHP HTML file does NOT call jQuery, if that is relevant.

Comment: The reference to document.body.XXX was causing the function assignment to fail. I tested this alternate code and it works. However, I will still have to test if it works when starting the browser. `var db = document.body;
var dde = document.documentElement;`

`myWidth = (document.body)?Math.max(db.scrollWidth,db.offsetWidth,db.clientWidth):
                          Math.max(dde.scrollWidth,dde.offsetWidth,dde.clientWidth);`

Answer (score 0):

> Make your website responsive which will help you to cover more number of visitors to your size, as most of the people use their smartphone to browse websites nowdays.

http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Answer (score 0):

Further testing this width error upon browser startup showed that it seems limited to Chromium-based browsers where the target tab is not the active one. In such cases, Google Chrome took its window width results from the non-maximized window size even though the window was actually maximized.

Two detection steps were required on the way to a solution:

(1) is the browser Chromium-based? --> `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome/")>0`

(2) is the tab inactive? --> `document.webkitVisibilityState == "hidden"`

test URL: http://www.gooplusplus.com/chrome-bug.html

my working solution:

```
<script>

var myWidth = 981 

var dde = document.documentElement;

var tabVisible = document.webkitVisibilityState;

if(!document.documentElement) dde = document.body; // fix for IE6 and earlier 

myWidth = Math.max(dde.scrollWidth,dde.offsetWidth,dde.clientWidth);

if( ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome/")<0 || tabVisible!="hidden" ) && myWidth < 960 ) 
    document.location.href="http://www.gooplusplus.com/mini.php";  

</script>
```

The above technique fixed the problem. Although the **@theJoeBiz** answer turned out to be irrelevant to the ultimate solution, his code was useful. I based my own `new myWidth` assignment code on his jQuery `Math.max` code, while noting that his code failed on my `non-jQuery web page` due to inclusion of pre-IE7 `document.body` variables (*see fix in code above*).